# Woocommerce - Hiding "SPECIALS" row if no products are on sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a site that has an Owl Carousel row dedicated to the Weekly Specials.

I am trying to hide this row if no products are listed as "On Sale". This is what I have so far, but something is not working and I can't figure out what. All help appreciated.

```
// -----------------------------------------
// HIDE WEEKLY SPECIALS IF THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS

function weeklyspecials() {
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array( // Variable products type
                        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<style>#weeklyspecials {display:none;}</style>';
        }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action ( 'wp_body_open', 'weeklyspecials' );
```

EDIT *** PROBLEM SOLVED

Turned out my issue lied in the fact that there were hidden ON SALE products... why? Because they were out of stock. I had to alter the array with an AND relation related to the stock status to ensure it covered everything.

WORKING CODE:

```
// HIDE WEEKLY SPECIALS IF THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS

function weeklyspecials() {
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array( // Variable products type
                        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    )),
                    array( // Stock status
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => 'instock'
                    )
                )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<style>#weeklyspecials {display:none;}</style>';
        }
}
add_action ( 'wp_body_open', 'weeklyspecials' );
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: where is the error? is there an error message we can work with?

Comment: There is no error. It simply either hides the row despite there being a product on sale. Or if I play around with it, it does nothing.

I believe the error is in my IF statement... but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Remove the `{display:none;}` to see if it shows them.

Comment: It does. That's not the issue though. The issue is that it isn't properly reacting to the instruction. I can hide the row, and I can unhide the row with this function... the problem is, when the row is hidden, if I put a product on sale... it doesn't unhide.

Comment: I was attempting to debug. If you want to show it if else, then I will add an answer.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Nope, nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` to your `if`.

```
// -----------------------------------------
// HIDE WEEKLY SPECIALS IF THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS

function weeklyspecials() {
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array( // Simple products type
                        'key'           => '_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array( // Variable products type
                        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value'         => 0,
                        'compare'       => '>',
                        'type'          => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<style>#weeklyspecials {display:none;}</style>';
        } else {
            echo '<style>#weeklyspecials</style>';
        }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action ( 'wp_body_open', 'weeklyspecials' );
```

Comment: Nothing. Think it might be a bigger issue. I'm pulling all of the products that are on sale with the array, and expecting it to have a 0 value if there are none... but that may not be the case... hmmm

Comment: can you update your question with the results of a `echo "<pre>"; print_r($loop); echo "</pre>";`?

Comment: I think I might have found whats causing the issue. There are out of stock products that have sale prices.

How can I go about settings conditions that will achieve my result, but treat the out of stock items as though they don't exist? Damn, thats a tricky one.